# Take JSpinner back to the last valid value on loss of focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, jspinner

How can I make the `JSpinner` go back to the last valid value when it loses focus and also when I press the spinner arrow button?

Comment: add some valid code demonstrating your problem

Comment: *"last valid value"* 1) What conditions determine what is valid? 2) Why not simply supply a `SpinnerModel` that only has valid values? 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter the OP seems to have abandoned.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, maybe the OP is busy celebrating christmas :-) With some more details it might become an interesting question.

Comment: @KarlP  Then maybe the OP should have delayed asking the question until they had time to attend to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) or adjust the spinner model to provide min/max values.  See [How to use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: *"adjust the spinner model to provide min/max values"*  Note that 'valid values' might be `{1,3,7}`  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson While I have no doubt of the truth of the comment, when the OP chooses to put more effort into their question, I'll put more effort into my answer ;)

Comment: I hear ya.  The question is sorely in need of extra details.

Comment: AFAIK not possible only by using DocumentFilter/DocumentListener (returns JFormattedTextField by default, but is possible to cast to JTextField) this issue is the same for number, date ........